# Autocreate logging file in a SOAP web service

Tags: xml, vb.net, web-services, logging, soap

I created an XML logging file to catch data of users using my webservice. I want to add a method that creates a new file, "log.xml", each month and renames the old one "log_lastMonthDate.xml". The problem is that I don't know where I have to implement this method as it is not a webmethod. Any hints?

NB: I am working in [Visual Studio 2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2010) with [SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) web service VB.NET coding.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using [Log4NET](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/) to handle logging your data. Its `log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender` allows a date or sized-based naming convention for your log files. There are some examples of configuration at [geekswithblogs](http://geekswithblogs.net/rgupta/archive/2009/03/03/tips-on-using-log4net-rollingfileappender.aspx).

Comment: I already created my logging file, and it is clear as it is in xml file, why should I search for another method? isn't there any other way just to create my file automatically? G Davison

Comment: The second link is (effectively) broken. It redirects to *[Geekswithblogs.net, the End of an Era](http://julian.farm/geekswithblogs/?url=/mtreadwell/archive/2004/06/06/6123.aspx)*.